# Task Scheduler failed to launch action "powershell.exe" How do i get around this?

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

My script is fairly simple. Just clearing out some AD group.

```
Get-ADGroupMember "ADGroup1" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "ADGroup1" $_ -Confirm:$false}

Get-ADGroupMember "ADGroup2" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "ADGroup2" $_ -Confirm:$false}

Get-ADGroupMember "ADGroup3" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "ADGroup3" $_ -Confirm:$false}
```

My Actions are also pretty straightforward.

And I do have run with highest privileges checked. However I keep getting "Action Failed to start", followed by "Task Failed to start" error and Last Result as "Directory name is invalid(0x8007010B) I am running it on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Who are you running the task as?

Comment: @DougMaurer Myself, same account as author. I ended up changing  Program/Script to C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE
Add Arguments to C:\Dev\ADAutomation.ps1
and Start in to C:\Dev\ 

And now the task completes but i get the 0x1 error.

Comment: Change arguments to -file c:\Dev\....

Answer (score 1):

In powershell 5.1 powershell.exe with no parameter defaults to `-Command` and you need to specify `-File`. If you're using powershell core 6+ it defaults to `-File` and you wouldn't need to specify. I've tested and confirmed you need to add at least `-File` for it to work. You can also clean up your script some like this.

```
"ADGroup1","ADGroup2","ADGroup3" | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-ADGroupMember $_ (Get-ADGroupMember $_) -Confirm:$false
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Doug, but i keep getting the 0x1 error no matter how i seem to change up the arguments. Could it be a privilege issue?

Comment: Look at the history tab.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
Program/Script:
powershell

Add arguments:
.\ADAutomation.ps1

Start in: 
"C:\Dev\"
```

As you are already changing the Start in directory there is no need to call the whole filepath.

Note the commas in the start in field

Comment: The error has just slightly changed to now be "Task Scheduler failed to launch action "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE" in instance ......"